# Dark mode Mac OS

Tags: macos, macos-darkmode

I received this error from Apple at the time of publication of my application. how can I solve this problem?
We found that when Dark Mode is enabled, the menu bar extra icons aren't visible.
I can not find anything online to define Dark mode...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image

Comment: You seem to have dark icons in the dark appearance area of your asset. They aren't going to be visible in dark mode.  You need light coloured images for dark mode

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, I entered them. now at the code level what should I do?

Comment: Nothing. The system selects the right appearance automatically. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/images_and_pdf/providing_images_for_different_appearances

Comment: You are referring to some error from Apple but haven't mentioned which. Also, I find it weird that your Xcode is in light mode but the editor has a dark scheme. Are you building on macOS 10.13? If so, [the dark mode colors and images won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53482255/400056)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the term `cache` in your code and taking some guesses:

It looks like you are loading the images, then manipulating them and storing the manipulated images for later use. There are a number of things you need to take care of:

First of all, make sure the current appearance is set correctly when you do your image loading/manipulation. Outside of `drawRect:` and a few other methods, you always need to do a dance similar to this:

```
NSAppearance * savedAppearance = [NSAppearance currentAppearance];
[NSAppearance setCurrentAppearance:someView.effectiveAppearance];

// Do your image/color/drawing stuff.

[NSAppearance setCurrentAppearance:savedAppearance];
```

Be aware that the appearance is "scoped" to a specific view! You can have different appearances in the same view hierarchy.

You need to either override `viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance` of your `NSView` or KVObserve the `effectiveAppearance` of a view to get notified about appearance changes and react accordingly (recreate your icons).